# jQuery animate left and bottom works, but not top and right

Tags: jquery

Why does jQuery animate bring a box to the right, and then to the bottom, and stop at that point?
I'm trying to get a box through a complete circle(or square to be exact) so that the box will return to its original position.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QZWDs/

Comment: `left` and `top` are positions, not commands to move a direction.  So you change the left position to make the object go left or right and you change the top position to make the object go up or down.  Instead of left and top, you can use bottom and right, but if you mix left and right or top and bottom, you will get a mess.  Pick one and only one in each direction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An element can have either a `top` or a `bottom` position and either a `left` or a `right`. It doesn't make sense to have all four. Use this to do the animation you want:

```
$(".block").animate({left:"150px"}, "slow")
           .animate({top:"150px"}, "slow")
           .animate({left:0},"slow")
           .animate({top:0}, "slow");
```

This uses only the `top` and `left` positions to animate it. Also it takes advantage of chaining, rather than calling `$(".block")` each time which creates a new jQuery object.

Comment: Great feedback - clear explanation of what was going on. Thanks for showing me chaining!

Comment: I'd just like to add that it does make complete sense for an element to have a top, bottom, left, and right. That's how you do things like position a div in the middle of the screen or make a div always fill the entire screen. I was actually personally hoping for a solution to animate all 4 so you could shrink or grow a div that is positioned this way.

Answer (score 1):

try out this

```
$("#right").ready(function(){

    $(".block").animate({left:"150px"},"slow", function () {
        $(".block").animate({bottom:"150px"},"slow", function () {
            $(".block").animate({left:"50px"},"slow", function () {
            $(".block").animate({top:"0px"},"slow");

            });
        });

    } );
});
```

Comment: One doesn't need to use the completion functions like this.  multiple animations on the same object are automatically queued and will run sequentially by default.  This isn't needed.

Comment: is there any drawback of using callbacks here, it functions the same. i mean to say that i not wrong in my answer but what does it makes less optimized. Please explain little as i am new to jQuery i have learned basic on my own.

Comment: A few disadvantages of your method: 1) You're creating a new jQuery object for every animation call instead of chaining the one object like in user1's answer.  2) Nesting multiple completion functions is just more complicated code to write and understand than letting the animation queue do the work for you - simpler code that works just as well is always better.  3) When using chaining, the `.stop()` method gives you control over what to do with the other queued animations and you don't have that level of control with completion function nesting.

Comment: Previous comment continued: 4) Any jQuery developer should learn how the animation queue works (rather than reinvent its functionality) because it makes lots of things a lot easier.

Comment: thanks for explaining. got something new to learn today. thats why i use stack site.. i always learn something in my every answer.